# Hotkeys not working in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.10, linux-headers

I recently bought an MSI GF63-11UC, the specs of it are:
i7-11800H, NVIDIA RTX3050, 144Hz 1920x1080 display. I am running Ubuntu 22.10 in it with kernel 6.1.8-generic [because there were some issues in the 5.19 kernel with suspend and black screen]. But in Ubuntu most of my keyboard hot keys don't work. I have the hotkeys listed below;

1. Fn+F2: Share Screen
2. Fn+F3: Disable Touchpad
3. Fn+F7: Don't know what, even in windows I can't figure out what's happening after pressing it
4. Fn+F10: airplane mode on/off

None of these hotkeys work. When I tried with `sudo evtest`

For Fn+F3 I get

```
vent: time 1675627344.350781, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 1d
Event: time 1675627344.350781, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1675627344.350781, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1675627344.360926, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value db
Event: time 1675627344.360926, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 1
Event: time 1675627344.360926, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1675627344.371105, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 76
Event: time 1675627344.371105, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 85 (KEY_ZENKAKUHANKAKU), value 1
Event: time 1675627344.371105, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1675627344.381271, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 1d
Event: time 1675627344.381271, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 0
Event: time 1675627344.381271, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1675627344.401541, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value db
Event: time 1675627344.401541, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 0
Event: time 1675627344.401541, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1675627344.411795, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 76
Event: time 1675627344.411795, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 85 (KEY_ZENKAKUHANKAKU), value 0
Event: time 1675627344.411795, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

For Fn+F2, I get

```
Event: time 1675627406.313712, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value db
Event: time 1675627406.313712, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 1
Event: time 1675627406.313712, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1675627406.324392, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value db
Event: time 1675627406.324392, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1675627406.334056, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 19
Event: time 1675627406.334056, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 25 (KEY_P), value 1
Event: time 1675627406.334056, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1675627406.384133, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 19
Event: time 1675627406.384133, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 25 (KEY_P), value 0
Event: time 1675627406.384133, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1675627406.385942, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value db
Event: time 1675627406.385942, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 125 (KEY_LEFTMETA), value 0
Event: time 1675627406.385942, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

For FnF7, I get

```
Event: time 1675627458.754096, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 8a
Event: time 1675627458.754096, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1675627458.756527, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 8a
Event: time 1675627458.756527, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

For Fn+F10, I get nothing. I have tried a lot of solutions, including trying to update the `60-keyboard.hwdb` file. Is there really no way to get those buttons work? Any help, suggestion, guide will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.